# Global scope for user snippet in Atom.io editor

Tags: sublimetext, atom-editor, code-snippets, language-comparisons

I would like to transform some snippets that I wrote for the [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) editor to the [atom.io](https://atom.io) editor.

Since I have a *"license"* snippet that is valid for any type of file (any file extension)  then in the `licence.sublime-snippet` file I did'n specify a scope:

```
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
```

Now, i see the above example in [atom/snippets](https://github.com/atom/snippets).

```
'.source.js':
  'console.log':
    'prefix': 'log'
    'body': 'console.log(${1:"crash"});$2'
```

> The outermost keys are the selectors where this snippets should be
>   active.

but I can't figure out how can I specify a *global scope* or better yet **do not specify it at all** as well as I did in `.sublime-snippet`. Any help is appreciated; in particular still have not found the comprehensive documentation of detailed operation snippet atom therefore also some links to this kind of docs are welcome.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
'*':
  'console.log':
    'prefix': 'log'
    'body': 'console.log(${1:"crash"});$2'
```

Comment: What if I need two types of source for the same snippet? for example js and html.

Answer (score 2):

@Basil Musa: For a snippet to be available in (js and html) files you specify it like this:

```
 '.html.js':
  'snippet-name':
    'snippet-shortcut': 'log'
    'snippet-body': 'console.log(${1:"placeholder"});$2'
```